# How to get element and its attribute which caret is positioned?

Tags: javascript, html, caret

I'm making rich editor with contenteditable div and I create `<p>` in contenteditable div by using this.

```
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p')
```

And I set id to each `<p>`. I'm trying to get element and attribute caret is positioned but I can't.
This is one of my attempt and I got `id=body-text` which is `<div>`s attribute, I need `<p>`s one.

Can anyone help me?

```
<div id='body-text' class='body-text' contenteditable=true data-placeholder='Body Contents'></div>


var div = document.getElementById('body-text')
div.addEventListener('keypress', onKeyPress)

function onKeyPress(e) {
    var check = document.activeElement
    console.log(check.getAttribute('id'))
}
```

**Supplementation**

In contenteditable div, there are lots of `<p>` not only one like below.

```
<div id='body-text' class='body-text' contenteditable=true data-placeholder='Body Contents'>
    <p id="1343">I have a problem</br>I can't handle it</p>
    <p id="1976">Please help me</p>
    <p id="1999">Thank you in advance</p>
</div>
```

**This is how I set id to each `<p>`**

```
var bodyContets = document.getElementById('body-text')
bodyContets.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp)

function onKeyUp(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode !== 13 || ( e.keyCode === 13 && (e.shiftKey === true || e.ctrlKey === true || e.altKey === true) )) {
        return false
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
    for (var i = 0; i <= elements.length - 1; i++) {
        if(!elements[i].hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            elements[i].id = i
            elements[i].tabIndex = i+1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there only ever one `<p>` in a `<div>`? If so, you can use div.firstChild.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have lots of `<p>` in a `<div>`, I add more info above my question. That's why I can't use div.firstChild. I don't know if caret is positioned in first `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `tabindex` property for the `<p>` element, it will allow it to have focus. Once it has focus, the `document.activeElement` property will return the `p` element instead of the `div`.

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/pt7z7yys/) which shows that it works. The code changed is below

```
<div id='body-text' class='body-text' contenteditable=true data-placeholder='Body Contents'>
    <p id="1343" tabIndex="1">I have a problem<br>I can't handle it</p>
    <p id="1976" tabIndex="2">Please help me</p>
    <p id="1999" tabIndex="3">Thank you in advance</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't know tabIndex. I tried this way and I found problem I have to click on `<p>` after going to new `<p>`. No one usually click. Do you come up with another way?

Comment: I would try... With `onKeyUp()`, go through the children of `check` and assign `tabIndex`if not already assigned. I can test this evening.

Comment: `tabIndex` is already assigned to each `<p>`, but it doesn't work.. I added how I assigned `tabIndex`.

Comment: @Hiro -  I've updated the fiddle. Mainly added and OR condition: `|| !elements[i].hasOwnProperty('tabIndex')` since if it already had an id it wouldn't assign a tabIndex. Also added code to assign the id and tabIndex when the document is loaded. I am not sure how your users get focus to the div to begin with, but I also added code that when div gets focus itself to transfer focus directly to the first p tag. Works for me. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you a lot for updating your fiddle. I tried your code on my application and on your fiddle. And I thick it doesn't work on both. What I want to get is id in `<p>`. For example on your fiddle, if caret is positioned in first line, I want to get `id="0"`. With your code I always get `id="body-text"`. I think  `<p>` still doesn't have focus.

Comment: It worked for me (in FF) but I can see that IE has problems. I am not sure you are going to find a cross browser solution. Interesting article on focus [here](https://nemisj.com/focusable/). Good luck and update if you find a better solution.

Comment: Oh I see. At least I want it to work on chrome. Thank you for a lot of advice and nice article. I will update when I solve this problem!!